# How to solve $x = \arccos(x)$

Tags: trigonometry

How does one solve
$$
x = \arccos(x)
$$
for $x$?

Is there an exact solution achievable by hand? I tried wolfram|alpha, but it only spits out the solution 
$$
x = \text{ root of }\quad x-\cos^{-1}(x) \quad \text{ near } x = 0.739085
$$

Comment: Think about the relationship between solving $x = \operatorname{arccos}(x)$ and $\cos x = x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no solution to this equation in terms of elementary functions. However, one can still use numerical methods to solve it (which is probably how Wolfram|Alpha generates the solution).

Comment: Thanks! I guess this renders [my work](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853240/find-intersections-of-two-ellipses-who-share-one-fixed-point) kind of useless...